# how to get time range from impressionist rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is hard but ... I am trying to count views for `impressionist gem`  on a specific time from date of last post till time.now and the code below doesn't seem to work as this message appear ?

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)

```
<%= @user.impressionist_count(:filter=>:ip_address, :start_date=>"#{current_user.posts.last.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}", :end_date=>"#{t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}") %>
```

post controller :

```
def show
  @user = current.user
  @post = Post.new
end
```

user model :

```
is_impressionable
has_many posts
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: UPDATED THE QUESTION BUT I THINK THE PROBLEM IS MORE OF A SYNTAX ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work properly.

```
<%= @user.impressionist_count(:filter => :ip_address, :start_date => 
current_user.posts.last.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), :end_date => 
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) %>
```